# How to create a que from daemon in rails app whithout getting "IOError: closed stream"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asynchronous, mongoid, eventmachine

In daemon, which tracks twitter-stream I have this construction:

```
client.track(*hashtags) do |status|
  if status.coordinates != nil
    EventMachine.synchrony 
      job = Qu.enqueue TweetProcessor, status
      puts "Enqueued tweet processing #{job.id}"
    end
  end
end
```

For ques library I'm using [qu-mongo](https://github.com/bkeepers/qu.) I have this config

```
# /config/initializers/qu.rb
Qu.configure do |c|
  c.connection = Mongo::Connection.new('127.0.0.1').db("appname_qu")
end
```

I've tried many options, but it always results with `IOError: closed stream`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809678/rails-3-daemons-gem-exception-when-querying-model). More on this you can read [here](http://blog.trikeapps.com/2011/05/12/daemonize-rails-3-scripts). So, in my case I've just reassign rails' logger and qu's loggers to the same file in the beginning of daemon's cycle and close it in the end, and everything is working out just fine:

```
client.track(*hashtags) do |status|
  parser_logger = ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger.new( File.join(Rails.root, "log", "qu.log"))
  Rails.logger = parser_logger
  Qu.configure do |c|
    c.connection  = Mongo::Connection.new.db("appname_qu")
    c.logger = parser_logger
  end
  job = Qu.enqueue TweetProcessor, status 
  Rails.logger.close
end
```