# Rails 3.1 + Daemons gem won't let me access my database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, scripting, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to setup a daemon for my Rails 3.1 app running on an Ubuntu server. Just something simple like this:

```
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment',  __FILE__)
require 'rubygems'
require 'daemons'

Daemons.run_proc('my_script') do
  loop do
    puts BlogPost.count
    sleep(5)
  end
end
```

But when I get to `BlogPost.count`, I get the following error:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:283:in `query': Mysql2::Error: MySQL server has gone away: SHOW FIELDS FROM `blog_posts` (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:283:in `execute'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:244:in `log'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:239:in `log'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:283:in `execute'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:473:in `columns'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:95:in `initialize'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:185:in `with_connection'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:92:in `initialize'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/base.rb:706:in `call'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/base.rb:706:in `default'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/base.rb:706:in `[]'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/base.rb:706:in `columns'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/base.rb:722:in `column_names'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:192:in `aggregate_column'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:213:in `execute_simple_calculation'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:187:in `perform_calculation'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:155:in `calculate'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:58:in `count'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/base.rb:445:in `__send__'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/base.rb:445:in `count'
from script/background_job_processor_control.rb:22
```

Any idea why my script can't connect to MySQL? If I put the `BlogPost.count` code before the `Daemons.run_proc`, I can connect to MySQL just fine.

---------- EDIT: SOLVED! ------------

For anyone curious as to the solution, I had to do three things to get this to work:

1. Include `bundle exec` when starting/stopping my daemon: `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec myscript.rb start`.
2. At this point I stopped getting the MySQL2 error, but started getting a logger error. The solution was to add the following code the `run_proc` block: `ActiveRecord::Base.logger = ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger.new('/path/to/log/file.log')`
3. Then I got a third error, and the solution was to require the Rails environment inside the `run_proc` block instead of earlier in the script.

My final script looks like this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'daemons'

Daemons.run_proc('my_script') do 
  require File.expand_path('../../config/environment',  __FILE__)
  ActiveRecord::Base.logger = ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger.new('/path/to/log/file.log')
  loop do
    puts BlogPost.count
    sleep(5)
  end
end
```

Comment: are you starting daemons with `bundle exec my_script_ctl start` ?

Comment: Hmm, no I was doing `RAILS_ENV=production ruby script/myscript_control.rb start`.

I just tried doing it your way, and now I'm getting a different error: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/buffered_logger.rb:109:in `write': closed stream (IOError)

Comment: So I followed the advice here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809678/rails-3-daemons-gem-exception-when-querying-model) to get rid of the logging error, and I got a new error that said some tables didn't exist in my development database. But I'm trying to run this on production, so I added `RAILS_ENV=production` in front of `bundle exec`, and now we're back to the original error of the "MySQL server has gone away". :(

Comment: So what was the other part of the story?

Comment: Loading the environment INSIDE the block instead of at the top of the file. I just edited my question with the full solution.

Comment: @NudeCanalTroll I'm trying to embed all my rails project and run it using daemon tool, I tried ur methods but it didn't work out , any help would be highly appreciated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13301174/i-cant-run-my-rails-application-with-daemons-gem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To properly preload Rails environment (dependencies) for the script, start it as follows:

```
bundle exec my_script_ctl start
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why, but it works when I disconnect the database connection before daemonizing the script, e.g.:

```
# app env
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = 'production'
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../config/environment")

# disconnect first
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!

# Become a daemon
Daemons.daemonize

# connect again
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection ENV['RAILS_ENV']

# ... do what you need
```

Hope this helps.