# I can't run my Rails application with daemons gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, daemon

I want to use Daemons gem with my Rails project so I can easily monitore it with Monit, this gem will allow me to create PIDs and use commands like start and stop .

Anyways it seems I can't use it with rails somehow, I create a file and named it admin :

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'daemons'

ROOT_PATH = File.expand_path("#{File.dirname __FILE__}/../")

require "#{ROOT_PATH}/config/environment"

Daemons.run("#{ROOT_PATH}/script/rails" , 
    :dir_mode => :system, 
    :log_output => true 
)
```

When I try to run it with :

```
bundle exec ./bin/admin run -- s
```

I get this error :

```
/Users/info/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/alt_system.rb:32: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.0.5 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
configuration /config.ru not found
Exiting
```

The config.ru file is there for sure. and I can run the application when I try to do it manually with command line, but for some reason I can daemonize the rails app .

I would appreciate any help since I spent all my day trying to iron this out .

Cheers

Comment: A few easy things to try - update Rails to the newest version and/or use thin instead of WEBrick (I think I've seen that error with WEBrick on a Mac, before). Even if they don't fix this problem, you'll be ahead...

Comment: @BradWerth thanks for your welling to help, I just tried to do so with thin using **sudo bundle exec ./bin/admin run -- s thin -p 80** but I got the exact same error , configuration /config.ru not found –

Comment: Updating rails ? I have 3.0.5 it's not that old , don't u think it's risky to do such a thing ? I mean i'm afraid for other gems to break specially that the newer release use assets which is a big step . let me ask you this if you don't mind , is it working at ur machine ? i mean if u do the same thing i did , will it work with u ?

Comment: Actually, 3.0.5 is pretty old, in terms of how many releases are behind it. FWIW, none of my production apps are running even one point release behind. I feel that it's risky NOT to update. Those releases contain many fixes related to security, and possibly one to resolve your issue as well. If you are talking of developer risk, it should be as easy as firing off your acceptance tests (or going through your whole app by hand). There probably won't be much to change...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May it be because `daemons` is not running the server in your application root directory ?

UPDATE

To launch Rails server from another path than your root app directory, use the `-c` option of `rails server` command which need the exact path to your `config.ru` file.

Comment: Thanks for the help here, but I'm running the script from the the root dir of my application, the admin script is at /bin directory in my rails project and i'm running it from within the root dir of my rails , any recommendations ?

Comment: Actually I moved the script to the rails root and did run it directly with **sudo bundle exec ./admin run -- s** but still getting the exact same error

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not familiar with `daemons gem`. To be sure that it executes the server in the proper directory, could you run the command `pwd` instead of `rails s` and see if it returns the root of the rails app ? I really think the config.ru error is because of the path where the server is executed.

Comment: of course i'm at the root dir of my app , the `pwd` will generate **/Users/info/code/myApp**, it seems daemons sets chdir to "/" always, because otherwise the running daemon could cause a filesystem to not be unmountable. It does this here:

[link](https://github.com/richo/daemons/blob/master/lib/daemons/daemonize.rb#L177) anyways I really don't know how to solve this out

Comment: Ok, I was not sure of that. Another solution : the `rails s` command as a `-c` option to set the path to the `config.ru` file. Could you try it ?

Comment: That's help alot now i'm not having the same error , it's just I'm facing problem stopping the service since it hang up by showing this message without doing anything **rails: trying to stop process with pid 19807...
** , thanks a lot for the help now things start moving again , cheers

Comment: I'm new at stackoverflow, how am I supposed to make ur comment as the right answer for my question ?

Comment: I have now updated my answer with this comment so you can just accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't directly solve your issue with daemons, but if you're on linux you can use start-stop-daemon to basically do the same thing. And you wouldn't need a script for it, just a one liner in your monit config which uses start-stop-daemon to daemonize the process.